# JSP/Servlet session for HTML5 apps packaged for Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, html, extjs, cordova

I am developing a HTML5 app using the Sencha framework that works against JSPs on the backend. I plan to package this into Android and iOS native app for distribution (thinking of PhoneGap or Sencha Cmd).

My app sometimes opens a new browser window for users to complete authorizations with oauth, then users return to the app. During this, I store some temp data in the session.

My question is that in the case of HTML5 apps packaged as native Android and iOS apps, when the app launches a new browser window and does some activity (like authorization) that places temp data in the session, then closes the window and returns to the app, does the app have access to those session objects? If the app then invokes JSPs, can the JSPs access the session objects that were placed by the browser window that was opened and closed previously?

I hope my question is clear. Let me know if I can provide any further clarifications. As always, any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible.

But..

Consider that most of the oauth services returns a token to the redirect-url as a param. So, If you are planning to use Phonegap/Cordova, and in that case you probably want to use the  inAppBrowser plugin.. you could listen to the url changes and extract the token from it.

Hope it helps-